# Sum the same node value (Amount) based on different grouping requirements

Tags: xslt-1.0

Most of the summing is the same; and I have that working.  The amount node is summed based on the concatenated key (<xsl:key name="kRcdGroup" match="Export/Record" use="concat(generate-id(..), AccountNo,Description,DeptName)"/>).  However, a new wrinkle appeared today - when the value of the AccountNo starts with USD then the amount needs to grouped by AccountNo and Description only, no DeptName.

I'm sure I can create a second key but I have no idea how to modify the xslt to use that second key.

I have searched the internet but most of the examples I found do not apply.

```
Here is a piece of my xml.

<Export>
    <Record>
        <AccountNo>80101</AccountNo>
        <Onsite></Onsite>
        <Amount>5404.39</Amount>
        <PayDate>14/07/2023</PayDate>
        <PPEndDate>07/31/2023</PPEndDate>
        <Description><![CDATA[Salaries - ]]></Description>
        <Desc><![CDATA[US Regular Earnings]]></Desc>
        <EmpNumber>100180</EmpNumber>
        <EmpFirstName><![CDATA[Aaron]]></EmpFirstName>
        <EmpLastName><![CDATA[Lugo]]></EmpLastName>
        <DeptName>Technical Services</DeptName>
        <DeptLedgerCode></DeptLedgerCode>
        <OnSiteName><![CDATA[GroundProbe North America - Office - Technical Services]]></OnSiteName>
        <SiteCode><![CDATA[]]></SiteCode>
        <LedgerCode><![CDATA[]]></LedgerCode>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <AccountNo>80104</AccountNo>
        <Onsite></Onsite>
        <Amount>-69.00</Amount>
        <PayDate>14/07/2023</PayDate>
        <PPEndDate>07/31/2023</PPEndDate>
        <Description><![CDATA[Medical Ins - ]]></Description>
        <Desc><![CDATA[US Medical Pre-Tax]]></Desc>
        <EmpNumber>100180</EmpNumber>
        <EmpFirstName><![CDATA[Aaron]]></EmpFirstName>
        <EmpLastName><![CDATA[Lugo]]></EmpLastName>
        <DeptName>Technical Services</DeptName>
        <DeptLedgerCode></DeptLedgerCode>
        <OnSiteName><![CDATA[GroundProbe North America - Office - Technical Services]]></OnSiteName>
        <SiteCode><![CDATA[]]></SiteCode>
        <LedgerCode><![CDATA[]]></LedgerCode>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <AccountNo>USD - GPNA</AccountNo>
        <Onsite></Onsite>
        <Amount>-343.63</Amount>
        <PayDate>14/07/2023</PayDate>
        <PPEndDate>07/31/2023</PPEndDate>
        <Description><![CDATA[Payroll Tax]]></Description>
        <Desc><![CDATA[FICA ER]]></Desc>
        <EmpNumber>100180</EmpNumber>
        <EmpFirstName><![CDATA[Aaron]]></EmpFirstName>
        <EmpLastName><![CDATA[Lugo]]></EmpLastName>
        <DeptName>Technical Services</DeptName>
        <DeptLedgerCode></DeptLedgerCode>
        <OnSiteName><![CDATA[GroundProbe North America - Office - Technical Services]]></OnSiteName>
        <SiteCode><![CDATA[]]></SiteCode>
        <LedgerCode><![CDATA[]]></LedgerCode>
    </Record>
```

```
Here is my xslt 1.0

<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    xmlns:vb="urn:the-xml-files:xslt-vb" version="1.0">

    <msxsl:script language="VBScript" implements-prefix="vb">
        <![CDATA[
        ]]>
    </msxsl:script>

    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:key name="kRcdGroup" match="Export/Record" use="concat(generate-id(..), AccountNo,Description,DeptName)"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>AccountNo,
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Export">
        <xsl:text>Company accounts,Date,GL Account,Account Type,Offset account,Offset account type,Description,Amount,GST group,Item GST group,Tax Invoice,Due date,Terms of payment,Payment ID,Document,Document date,Method of payment,Payment specification,Bank transaction type,Payment reference,Quantity,Approved,Approved by,Exchange rate,Currency,Line property,Category,Employee,Cost price,Quantity,Sales currency,Sales price,GST group,Item GST group,Team/Department,Revenue stream,Contact,Customer site,Team,Revenue stream,Contact,Customer site,Offset company accounts</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#x0D;&#x0A;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="Record[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kRcdGroup',concat(generate-id(..), AccountNo,Description,DeptName))[1])] ">
            <xsl:sort select="AccountNo" />
            <xsl:sort select="DeptName" />
            
            <xsl:variable name="vkeyGroup" select="key('kRcdGroup', concat(generate-id(..), AccountNo,Description,DeptName)) "/>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="DeptLedgerCode = '303'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'GPTU'"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'GPNA'"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="PayDate"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(DeptName, 'Misc')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('VM',AccountNo)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="AccountNo"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(DeptName, 'Misc')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'Vendor'"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains(AccountNo, 'USD')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'Bank'"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'Ledger'"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>,,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(AccountNo, 'USD')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(Description,DeptName)"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($vkeyGroup/Amount),'#.00')"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="'NA'"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="'NA'"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>,,,,,,,,,,,,,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="'1'"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="'USD'"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>,,,,,,,,,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="DeptLedgerCode"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="'9999'"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>,,,,,,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="DeptLedgerCode = '303'">
                <xsl:value-of select="'GPTU'"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>&#x0D;&#x0A;</xsl:text>

        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is this line of code - <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($vkeyGroup/Amount),'#.00')"/> - that needs to use a different Key to sum by.

Thank you very much.  Greg

Comment: Thanks for the views, I figured it out - two individual for-each loops each using separate grouping keys.  Greg